# aligning pointer operations

Tags: c++, c, pointers, typedef, memory-alignment

I want to have a variable for example as of type int (aligned as 8 bytes) and so I also want to have pointer operations on it in 8 bytes. ( target pointer alignment)

I did the following but couldnt make it.

```
typedef int int_align_double __attribute__ ((aligned(sizeof(double))));
typedef int_align_double* pint_align_double;
pint_align_double pint;
```

or also

```
typedef int_align_double* pint_align_double __attribute__ ((aligned(sizeof(double))));
```

So that

```
(int)&pint[1]-(int)&pint[0] == 8
```

but it is equal to 4.
Am I missing something?
I've also found this discussion : http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2010-01/msg00005.html
but didn't provide a solution or whether it is a bug or not.

Comment: The alignment specifier is only going to affect the first address, not the spacing between addresses.

Comment: for data structures you usually want `__attribute__(packed)`

Comment: The size of a pointer is determined by the CPU architecture and the *bit* -ness (32 or 64) of the OS running the machine.

Comment: @ajay and the ABI too

Comment: On a 64-bit machine running a 64-bit OS (Ubuntu, for example), I can compile a program into 32-bit executable by passing the `-m32` flag. The machine would *appear* to the program as if it were 32-bit.

Comment: @MarkRansom so how come if I do 

typedef long long int_align_double;

it calculates spacings correctly. I mean shouldn't it be allowed to somehow achieve this?

Comment: @ajay try the mx32 ABI

Comment: Maybe because `sizeof(long long) == sizeof(double)`?

Comment: @MarkRansom both `long` and `double` have only minimum requirements to meet, they have unspecified size according to the standard, you can't write that.

Comment: @user2485710, I meant in the context of a specific compiler and processor, not in general across the board. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use attribute `vector_size`, which specifies the vector size for the variable in bytes, instead of `aligned`.

So try this:

```
typedef int int_align_double __attribute__ ((vector_size(sizeof(double))));
```

Comment: thanks. It worked. So is it only for computers with  i386 the MMX, 3DNow! and SSE extensions? Or is it general c/c++ standard? for example does it work on arm?

Comment: @RoozbehG I believe `__attribute__` is a compiler specific extension, not part of the standard.

Comment: @RoozbehG It is a GCC extension for C, should work for all architectures that GCC supports.

Answer (score 3):

The alignment specifier is going to affect the alignment of the first element of an array, but it won't affect the spacing of elements within the array.

If you need to control the spacing of the elements, use a `union`.

```
union spaced_int
{
    int    i;
    double d;
};
```

Edit: Disregard the following, I didn't see that the pointers were being cast to `int` before the subtraction.

> Also note that subtracting two pointers will always yield the difference in terms of the size of the elements, in your example the answer will always be `1`.